# Allow expand/collapse buttons usage in a protected Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need to protect/unprotect the excel file using a macro, but I still need to be able to use the expand/collapse buttons while the file is protected. Here is the picture:

[collapse/expand buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnoHS.png)

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub IPMR()
'
' IPMR Macro
'
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="XXX"
'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FacilityName"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FacilityName").CurrentPage _
        = "Inst of Physical Med and Rehab"

        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        Set pf = pt.RowFields("Row Labels")
        pf.EnableItemSelection = True

    Sheet1.Protect Password:="XXX"
End Sub
```

However, when I use this, I get the error :Unable to get RowFields property of the PivotTable class. Please guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to define Row Labels, you should have a title for it, try the following code:

```
Sub showDetailsinPT()
'I think your title in row lables is FacilityName?
Dim TotalPTItem As PivotItems: Set TotalPTItems = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FacilityName").PivotItems
Dim CounterPTItem As PivotItem

For Each CounterPTItem In TotalPTItems
CounterPTItem.ShowDetail = True
Next CounterPTItem
End Sub
```

Picture of working code:
[image]

Comment: Unable to set the showDetail property of the PivotItem class

Comment: did you take out the sheet protection?